# How to use SqlBulkCopy with a Table's whose SchemaName has a period?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-3.5, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using the following code to insert data into a MS SQL 2008 Server:

```
//filter the data have only the latest values
DataTable table = GetFilteredTable(id, maxTime);

//upload these values
using (SqlBulkCopy blk = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
{
 blk.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
 blk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
 blk.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

These tables are made in SQL Server, by an Enterprise MiddleWare, and as a result has a period in the schema name. The complete Table is name is something like `[j.doe].[FOOBAR]` where j.doe is the schema name & FOOBAR is the actual table Name.

When I run the Above code, it fails with an exception which means 'Unable to get ordering information for columns in destination table. (I'm not attaching the exact error message since the server has french locale, and the exception is in french as well.)

In my code, the value of the variable `tableName` is `[j.doe].[FOOBAR]`

Just to make sure that the error is in the table name, I created the same table in another schema, i.e `[dbo].[FOOBAR]`, and the same code runs without any issue, when inserting to this table.

I would prefer to use the correct programatical way to insert rows into this table. So please suggest how I should change my code, rather than changing or adding new tables in the Database on the server.

How Do I use SqlBulkCopy when the schema name has a period?

Comment: Would using bulk insert into a temporary table be acceptable? If so you could simply insert them into the real table afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I have a few thousand rows and need to get them into that table as quickly as possible. That is why I was using SqlBulkCopy instead of individual insert statements

Comment: Sorry, I was perhaps a bit unclear. You would use SqlBulkCopy with a temporary table, and then execute 1 insert that would copy from that temporary table into the real table. Not 1 insert per row, you would basically do this: `INSERT INTO realtable SELECT * FROM temptable`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I would prefer If I didn't have to do this additional step, and could insert directly into the required table. This is because it would be very difficult to justify this 'hack' to our DBA, when possibly there is a correct way to do this.

Comment: What's the value of `tableName` now?

Comment: @neoistheone: The value of the variable `tableName` is `[j.doe].[FOOBAR]`

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to find out what SQL is being sent. That might give you a clue to what a workaround might be.

Comment: The error occurs in `CreateAndExecuteInitialQuery`. The parsing logic there is quite funky and I can spot at least one bug.